High Court order vs Notification
In India, in the context of a subject in the concurrent list, if an older High Court order is repugnant to a relatively newer Notification issued by a Ministry in the Government of India, what legally outweighs the other?
A 2018 Bombay HC order is incompatible with a Union ministry's notification issued in 2019 and I am wondering which one to refer to. I live in the territory jurisdiction of Bombay HC. Article 254 of the Constitution states that on subjects in the concurrent list, the central laws supercede the state laws if the latter are found to be repugnant to the former, irrespective of the time of the former's coming into force. This establishes the hierarchy of laws. However, I couldn't finding a counterpart of this hierarchy relevant to my question.
